# how create a view when custom button click

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

new developer on iphone,please any one have an idea about my problem tell me.in my application take two views one login another one is main message view,user enter valid username,password when click login button main message view will display i wrote for this but my problem is in main message view i place tableview to display all messages and rigth side of this tableview place a button type is custom when click this button add a small view(this view add to main message view both view will display at that time)on that new add view we have to add some buttons one by one(world,country,state)when click world button data change on main message tableview.

Comment: hey it's complicated to get ur question until you give the clue about how many view u are using and what is the flow of ur application..

Answer (score 0):

please elaborate the problem.

Where exactly you are having problem?
In adding view? or buttons?... you are saying you want to add button one by one....... is it side by side? or you want to give some time delay to add these buttons?
Or you are having problem in data updation on main view?

But as your question title suggests you are having problem in creating the view. I think you want know how to add action with that custom button?(not sure)

```
[yourBtnObject addTarget:self action:@selector(yourBtnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

here in above code you have to define method:

```
-(void) yourBtnAction:(id)sender{
//you code goes here for creating and adding the view. 
}
```

also, `yourBtnObject` denotes your customButton reference ..... change the names as suitable.

Thanks,